# Request returns less results than page really has in my crawler

Tags: javascript, http, web-crawler

When I make a request from [Mercadoline](https://www.mercadoline.com.br/salvador/index.php?route=product/category&path=324_255#/sort=pd.name/order=ASC/limit=1000/minPrice=1/maxPrice=1000). In My browser returns all results, in this case 35.

But If I use request module from NodeJS or Postman to make this request I receive just 20 results(products from market online) and this happens with all pages.

I have applied this xpath in html `//div[@class='name']//a//text()`.

Someone knows Why It's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because after the page is loaded, an Ajax request is sent to get product list, and replace the page content after this product list data is fetched.

Here is some detail explanation:

1. When browser visit the [URL](https://www.mercadoline.com.br/salvador/index.php?route=product/category&path=324_255#/sort=pd.name/order=ASC/limit=1000/minPrice=1/maxPrice=1000) you provided. A `GET` request is sent and an HTML file is retrieved. In this file, there are 20 results. In Node.js or Postman, this is exactly what happens: HTML resource is retrieved, nothing more.
2. In browser, after the page is loaded, an Ajax request is sent: `POST https://www.mercadoline.com.br/salvador/index.php?route=module/journal2_super_filter/products&module_id=13`. The Ajax response returns HTML block which contains 35 results.
3. The script in the site gets these 35 results and replaces the page content. That's why you see 35 results in the browser.

To get the real results in the crawler, it needs to send `POST` HTTP request to `https://www.mercadoline.com.br/salvador/index.php?route=module/journal2_super_filter/products&module_id=13`, not the address of the page.

Comment: You're right man. Thx for your response. It will be very useful.